# Range not found - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Please bear with me, I'm a noob at JavaScript. I'm getting "Range not found" (line 5) when trying to run this code in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
function saveData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var url = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1').getValue();
 var follower_count = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B1').getValue();
 var date = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!C1').getValue();
 sheet.appendRow([url,follower_count,date]); 
}
```

My sheet contains values in all the those cells `(A1,B1,C1)`. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your script runs fine for me. Show us your data. Can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: Is your sheet still named "Sheet1"?

Comment: @EdNelson Here you go: https://docs.google.com/a/getrocket.com.br/spreadsheets/d/10XDXAi-ycOlKIPDjmdmsLh-0pTDyYdtcMDnRialSWnw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoshDawson Good thinking, it wasn't. I'm still getting the error after changing it however .

Answer (score 0):

if your sheet's name is **Sheet1** then try this piece:

```
function saveData() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var url = sheet.getRange('A1').getDisplayValue();
   var follower_count = sheet.getRange('B1').getDisplayValue();
   var date = sheet.getRange('C1').getDisplayValue();
   sheet.appendRow([url,follower_count,date]);
}
```